# Request Headers: 41d9251ae3b6e89193fe, what does it mean?

Tags: python-3.x, request, scrapy, web-crawler

As we know, the general request headers are always like "***User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36***", or "***Accept:application/json, text/plain***".

But this time, I find a request header: "***41d9251ae3b6e89193fe:1b237fc9847ec56e144031e03cc72d704777ef4167026f236eb3dd8d2c5b15ad837a20c8ce14459ae9f5c36e581b1322229b548178cce6cdf07ebbea7765f2df***", and I have never seen a request header like that.

What does it mean?

Comment: Please show the code which makes the request and the URL of the site you are scraping.

Comment: I have just solved it, thx anyway

Comment: Good to hear you have soled your problem. Perhaps you could post an answer to your own question describing the fix? Then others finding your question will know what to do.

Comment: Sorry>_<I'm a fresh in this community...it's just a header using the MD5 encryption, i find the way of encryption in its .js by using the chrome developer tools, just debug the .js file.

Comment: No need to apologise. Thanks for the comment but you should post it as an answer. [Answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on Stackoverflow is encouraged, and you can [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) too so the question will not show up as "unanswered". You already have one other user who has marked this as a "favorite" question, I'm sure they would like to see the answer.